# JQuery converting anonymous function to named function doesn't works correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `js` file with one `$(document).ready..` block. Since there are many anonymous functions inside this block, I've decided to move them and create functions. The problem is that when I've changed anonymous function to function, js stopped working properly.

In this case, I'm trying to create a `destination_from_0_changed` function to avoid anonymous.

For example:

**BEFORE** (works)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var destination_from_0 = $("#id_form-0-destination_from");
    var destination_to_0 = $('#id_form-0-destination_to');
    destination_from_0.on('change', function () {
        var destination_id = $(this).val();
        if (destination_id==''){
            return;
        }
        var ajax_loading_image = $('#ajax-loading-image');
        destination_to_0.empty();
        ajax_loading_image.show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/get-destination-to-options/' + destination_id + '/',
            success: function (data) {
                ajax_loading_image.hide();
                destination_to_0.append('<option value="" selected="selected">'+"---------" + '</option>');
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    destination_to_0.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                });
                destination_to_0.change();
            }
        })
    });
```

**NOW:** (doesn't work)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var destination_from_0 = $("#id_form-0-destination_from");
    var destination_to_0 = $('#id_form-0-destination_to');
    destination_from_0.on('change', function(){
        destination_from_0_changed(destination_to_0);
    });

function destination_from_0_changed(destination_to_0){
    var destination_id = $(this).val();
        if (destination_id==''){
            return;
        }
        var ajax_loading_image = $('#ajax-loading-image');
        destination_to_0.empty();
        ajax_loading_image.show();
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ajax/get-destination-to-options/' + destination_id + '/',
            success: function (data) {
                ajax_loading_image.hide();
                destination_to_0.append('<option value="" selected="selected">'+"---------" + '</option>');
                $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                    destination_to_0.append('<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>');
                });
                destination_to_0.change();
            }
        })
}
```

Do you guys know where the problem is?

Comment: your `this` has changed ... you haven't got rid of anonymous function anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem with you implementation is that current element context `this` doesn't refers to the element which invoked the event.

You can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

> The `bind()` method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

*Code*

```
destination_from_0.on('change', function(){
    destination_from_0_changed.bind(this)(destination_to_0);
});
```

OR, You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

> The `call()` method calls a function with a given `this` value and arguments provided individually.

```
destination_from_0.on('change', function(){
    destination_from_0_changed.call(this, destination_to_0);
});
```

---

Comment: or you could use .call to avoid that nasty syntax

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get rid of the anonymous function altogether, you can change the code to

```
destination_from_0.on('change', destination_from_0_changed.bind(destination_from_0, destination_to_0));
```